# Can Android access the in app purchase of any application in android

Tags: android, mobile

I am developing an application for android, I need the access to the in app purchase that have done from the mobile of any application

Comment: Without knowing it I am pretty confident to say: of course not, no, that would be huge security / privacy concern.

Comment: @luk2302 it is possible, when user click in app purchase than we save that info in our application